# The elements in the article are not centered while the margin is set to auto

Tags: html, css

I am working on a simple website project. [Which you can see here](http://udayk8139.github.io/Faith-and-God/) 
I have so-far completed the header, menu and now Im in body.
I am trying to center the cards of the article named "Bible Stories"
They are centered in my PC but they are not centered if I try to resize my browser. I want to see if it appears centered on all the screen sizes
Now the main problem pops up here..

Here's the code of the article.

HTML:

```
<div class='articles'>
            <h1>Bible Stories</h1>
            <div class='cardholder'>
            <center>
                <!-- Story Cards -->
                    <!-- 1st Card -->
                    <div class="card red">
                      <center>
                        <img class="avatar" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/184510/profile/profile-512_2.jpg">
                        <h1 class="name"> Uday Kiran </h1>
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  </p>
                      </center>
                    </div>
                    <!-- 2nd Card -->
                    <div class="card blue">
                      <center>
                        <img class="avatar" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/184510/profile/profile-512_2.jpg">
                        <h1 class="name"> Uday Kiran </h1>
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  </p>
                      </center>
                    </div>
                    <!-- 3rd Card -->
                    <div class="card green">
                      <center>
                        <img class="avatar" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/184510/profile/profile-512_2.jpg">
                        <h1 class="name"> Uday Kiran </h1>
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  </p>
                      </center>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                </div>
                <!-- End of story cards -->

            </div>
```

and here is the CSS of the article:

```
.articles{
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #3A4042;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', serif;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 100px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
}

.articles > h1{
    color: #4F4F4F;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display:block;
    background: #EDEDED;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.articles > .cardholder{
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 1em auto;   
}
```

Oh and the CSS for the cards you see:

```
.name{
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(127, 123, 117, .5);
}

.avatar{
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 100px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.card p{
    margin: 1em;
}

.card{
  float:left;
  margin: 0 0 0 4.5em;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', serif;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
}

.blue{background-color: #3992BD;}
.red{background-color:#BF6E55;}
.green{background-color: #39BD81}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated

Comment: Will there always be  rows of 3 cards ?

Comment: Yes, there will always be 3 cards and thanks I didn't know center is deprecated. :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your article inside div with marign 0  auto and inside text-align center.

An example for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/47b64wbw/3/

## Bible Stories

Uday Kiran

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Uday Kiran

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Uday Kiran

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

```
.articles{
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #3A4042;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', serif;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 100px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
}

.articles > h1{
    color: #4F4F4F;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display:block;
    background: #EDEDED;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.articles > .cardholder{
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 1em auto;   
    text-align: center; /*new style */
}

.name{
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(127, 123, 117, .5);
}

.avatar{
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 100px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.card p{
    margin: 1em;
}

.card{
  float:left;
  margin: 0 0 0 4.5em;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', serif;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
}

.blue{background-color: #3992BD;}
.red{background-color:#BF6E55;}
.green{background-color: #39BD81}

/* new class*/
.center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Woah! Thanks alot! But is there a way so that I could just put the center class onto the cardholder element? (I made the card holder element solely for this purpose)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the width of the card-holder and card dynamically by providing in `%`. It looks centered in by when I applied `margin-left: 10%;` for cards.

If you want responsive design, I would suggest you to use Bootstrap.

```css
.articles{
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #3A4042;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', serif;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 100px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
}

.articles > h1{
    color: #4F4F4F;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display:block;
    background: #EDEDED;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.articles > .cardholder{
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 1em auto;   
  position: relateive
}
.name{
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(127, 123, 117, .5);
}

.avatar{
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 100px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.card p{
    margin: 1em;
}

.card{
  float:left;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 4.5em;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', serif;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
}

.blue{background-color: #3992BD;}
.red{background-color:#BF6E55;}
.green{background-color: #39BD81}
```

```html
<div class='articles'>
            <h1>Bible Stories</h1>
            <div class='cardholder'>
            <center>
                <!-- Story Cards -->
                    <!-- 1st Card -->
                    <div class="card red">
                      <center>
                        <img class="avatar" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/184510/profile/profile-512_2.jpg">
                        <h1 class="name"> Uday Kiran </h1>
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  </p>
                      </center>
                    </div>
                    <!-- 2nd Card -->
                    <div class="card blue">
                      <center>
                        <img class="avatar" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/184510/profile/profile-512_2.jpg">
                        <h1 class="name"> Uday Kiran </h1>
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  </p>
                      </center>
                    </div>
                    <!-- 3rd Card -->
                    <div class="card green">
                      <center>
                        <img class="avatar" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/184510/profile/profile-512_2.jpg">
                        <h1 class="name"> Uday Kiran </h1>
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  </p>
                      </center>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                </div>
                <!-- End of story cards -->

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This really needs to be done responsively, but this code meets your needs *as presented*.

```css
.articles{
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #3A4042;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', serif;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 100px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
}

.articles > h1{
    color: #4F4F4F;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display:block;
    background: #EDEDED;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.articles > .cardholder{
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 1em auto;   
}

.name{
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(127, 123, 117, .5);
}

.avatar{
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 100px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.inner {
  width: 1120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card p{
    margin: 1em;
}

.card{
  float:left;
  margin: 0 0 0 4.5em;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', serif;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
}

.blue{background-color: #3992BD;}
.red{background-color:#BF6E55;}
.green{background-color: #39BD81}
```

```html
<div class='articles'>
  <h1>Bible Stories</h1>
  <div class='cardholder'>
    <div class="inner">
      <!-- Story Cards -->
      <!-- 1st Card -->
      <div class="card red">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/184510/profile/profile-512_2.jpg">
        <h1 class="name"> Uday Kiran </h1>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      </div>
      <!-- 2nd Card -->
      <div class="card blue">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/184510/profile/profile-512_2.jpg">
        <h1 class="name"> Uday Kiran </h1>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      </div>
      <!-- 3rd Card -->
      <div class="card green">
        <img class="avatar" src="http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/184510/profile/profile-512_2.jpg">
        <h1 class="name"> Uday Kiran </h1>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of story cards -->

</div>
```

**Key code updates**

- removed deprecated `<center>` tags
- wrapped cards in a `<div class="inner">`
- added a CSS class as below...

  .inner {
    width: 1120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use the center tag as has been mentioned. However, using your code, it is pretty simple to center the cards by removing

`float: left;` from .cards and replacing with `display: inline-block`

Using inline-block means the `<div>` behaves like an inline element like `<span>` and will respond to either the center tag (don't use this) or `text-align: center`